# Accessing key, value in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I know questions regarding accessing key, value in a nested dictionary have been asked before but I'm having some trouble with the following piece of my code:

For accessing the keys and values of a nested dictionary as follows:

```
example_dict = {'key_outer_01': {'key_inner_01': 'value_inner_01'},
                'key_outer_02': {'key_inner_02': 'value_inner_02'}}
```

I have the following piece of code:

```
def get_key_value_of_nested_dict(nested_dict):
    for key, value in nested_dict.items():
        outer_key = None
        inner_key = None
        inner_value = None
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            outer_key = key
            get_key_value_of_nested_dict(value)
        else:
            inner_key = key
            inner_value = value
        return outer_key, inner_key, inner_value
```

The output that I'm getting is:

```
    key_outer_01 None None
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what would you like to be getting?

Comment: You are assigning inner_key and inner_value as None

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: I'd like to be getting the outer key, inner key and the inner value for every iteration.

Comment: @Harsha: Yes, I think I'm doing something wrong with the assignment there.

Comment: I already provided an answer, but I'm not satisfied. Do you want to get the next `value_inner` at each iteration ? You might want to `yield`, instead of `return`.

Comment: @IMCoins: Yes, I do want the next value_inner at each iteration. So far, your solution seems to working fine.

Comment: I meant : Do you want the next `value_inner` at each call of your function. My example would only work if the data is formatting exactly as your example_dict. What if there are 2 `key_inner` : `value_inner` in `key_outer` ?

Comment: As of now, I only have 1 `key_inner : value_inner` in my dictionary. I haven't tried out any other corner cases so far.

Comment: I edited my answer, for something I thought would be better. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your recursive call, you are setting **outer_key**, **inner_key** and **inner_value** to `None`. But in the `if isintance(value, dict)`, you are only redifining **outer_key** to `key`. You might want to assign the new values of `inner_key` and `inner_value`.

Assign new value to `inner_key` and `inner_value` ! Such as :

```
example_dict = {'key_outer_01': {'key_inner_01': 'value_inner_01'},
                'key_outer_02': {'key_inner_02': 'value_inner_02'}}

def get_key_value_of_nested_dict(nested_dict):
    for key, value in nested_dict.items():
        outer_key = None
        inner_key = None
        inner_value = None
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            outer_key = key
            _, inner_key, inner_value = get_key_value_of_nested_dict(value)
        else:
            inner_key = key
            inner_value = value
        return outer_key, inner_key, inner_value

print get_key_value_of_nested_dict(example_dict)
# outputs : ('key_outer_01', 'key_inner_01', 'value_inner_01')
```

---

I believe we need more information whereas all the edge-cases to know if this code is good or not.

---

I tried for fun some kind of improvement, tell me if it suits your case better than your original code.

```
example_dict = {'key_outer_01': {'key_inner_01': 'value_inner_01', 'key_inner_02' : 'value_inner_02'},
                'key_outer_02': {'key_inner_02': 'value_inner_02'},
                'key_outer_03' : None}

def get_k_v_of_inner(nested_dict):
    for k, v in nested_dict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for k_nested, v_nested in v.items():
                yield {k : {k_nested : v_nested}}
        else:
            # do_something, or simply ignore if not nested dict.
            pass

gen = get_k_v_of_inner(example_dict)

for c, value in enumerate(gen):
    print '#{} : {}'.format(c, value)

# outs : #0 : {'key_outer_01': {'key_inner_02': 'value_inner_02'}}
         #1 : {'key_outer_01': {'key_inner_01': 'value_inner_01'}}
         #2 : {'key_outer_02': {'key_inner_02': 'value_inner_02'}}
```

Comment: In First Code Snippet why only ('key_outer_01', 'key_inner_01', 'value_inner_01') is returning what about the 'key_outer_02'?

Comment: @Pradam I know right, I just fixed OP's code, but what he wants is unclear even though he seems happy with my fix. I have the same interrogation as you, hence my second answer which provides (imo) a best answer to this. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a nested `dict`, you need a nested `for` loop:

```
def print_items(nested_dict):

    for key, dictionary in my_dict.items():

        for inner_key, value in dictionary.items():
            print(key, inner_key, value)

my_dict = {"a": {"b": "c", "d": "e"}, "f": {"g": "h"}}
print_items(my_dict)
```

This prints:

```
a b c
a d e
f g h
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing for sure is you need a `return` here

```
if isinstance(value, dict):
        outer_key = key
        get_key_value_of_nested_dict(value)
```

---

```
return get_key_value_of_nested_dict(value)
```

Comment: This also works perfectly. But can you please explain the reason for the need of the `return` statement in the first `if` block?

Comment: @ShamimAkhtar Your call to the `get_key_value_of_nested_dict(value)` function returns a value. If you want to return the value of it, from your function, you need to return with a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
example_dict = {'key_outer_01': {'key_inner_01': 'value_inner_01'}, 'key_outer_02': {'key_inner_02': 'value_inner_02'}}

def get_key_value_of_nested_dict(nested_dict, outer_key=None):
    inner_key = None
    inner_value = None
    for key, value in nested_dict.items():

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            outer_key = key
            return get_key_value_of_nested_dict(value, key)
        else:
            inner_key = key
            inner_value = value
        return outer_key, inner_key, inner_value

print get_key_value_of_nested_dict(example_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
('key_outer_01', 'key_inner_01', 'value_inner_01')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_key_value_of_nested_dict(nested_dict):
    rv = []
    for outer_key, value in nested_dict.items():
        try:
            # first we leap
            inner_kvs = get_key_value_of_nested_dict(value)
            for inner_keys, inner_value in inner_kvs:
                rv.append(([outer_key]+inner_keys, inner_value))
        except AttributeError:
            # then ask for forgiveness
            rv.append(([outer_key], value))
    return rv
```

You get a list of tuples. In each tuple the first element is a list of your keys and the second is the final value.

```
example_dict = {'key_outer_01': {'key_inner_01': 'value_inner_01'},
                'key_outer_02': {'key_inner_02': 'value_inner_02'}}

get_key_value_of_nested_dict(example_dict)

# output
[(['key_outer_01', 'key_inner_01'], 'value_inner_01'),
 (['key_outer_02', 'key_inner_02'], 'value_inner_02')]
```

To simply get a list of tuples with no inner list of keys just change the function a bit:

```
def get_key_value_of_nested_dict(nested_dict):
    rv = []
    for outer_key, value in nested_dict.items():
        try:
            inner_kvs = get_key_value_of_nested_dict(value)
            for i_kvs in inner_kvs:
                rv.append((outer_key,) + i_kvs)
        except AttributeError:
            rv.append((outer_key, value))
    return rv

get_key_value_of_nested_dict(example_dict)

# output
[('key_outer_01', 'key_inner_01', 'value_inner_01'),
 ('key_outer_02', 'key_inner_02', 'value_inner_02')]
```